# How get html in div element with class?

Tags: php, dom, file-get-contents

**Good day.**

**ROWS DOM HTML:**

```
<div class="raw_data">

<span data-bind-domain="raw_registrar_lookup">

Domain Name: ABATE.COM
<br>
Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
<br>
Registrant Name: Jim Elgin
<br>
Registrant Organization: ABATE of Ohio, Inc.
<br>
Name Server: NS43.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
<br>
Name Server: NS44.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
<br>

<br>
For complete domain details go to:
<br>
http://who.godaddy.com/whoischeck.aspx?domain=ABATE.COM<br>
    <br>
    Information Updated: Wed, 4 Sep 2013 23:43:18 UTC<br>



</span>

</div>
```

**For get html div with class name *raw_data* i use code:**

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://who.is/whois/abate.com');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$res = $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),"raw_data")]');
```

***but not working...***

***1) Tell me please where error?***

***2) Can i get html only in span `<span data-bind-domain="raw_registrar_lookup">` ?***

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can get only information with `<span>..</span>` is using preg_match. Regex parsing of HTML can be a chore but here's a working example with the data you provided.

```
$data = '
<div class="raw_data">

<span data-bind-domain="raw_registrar_lookup">

Domain Name: ABATE.COM
<br>
Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
<br>
Registrant Name: Jim Elgin
<br>
Registrant Organization: ABATE of Ohio, Inc.
<br>
Name Server: NS43.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
<br>
Name Server: NS44.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
<br>

<br>
For complete domain details go to:
<br>
http://who.godaddy.com/whoischeck.aspx?domain=ABATE.COM <br>
    <br>
    Information Updated: Wed, 4 Sep 2013 23:43:18 UTC<br>

</span>

</div>';

preg_match("/<span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/si", $data, $matches);
//           ^         ^       ^    ^
//           <span.....>      </span>
//                                    s = make dot match all characters
//                                    i = case insensitive search

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Does this help?

Another method would be to use `xml_parse_into_struct`.